# How can I play my lottie animation with an OnTapGesture event?

Tags: swift, swiftui, lottie

I followed MengTo's example of how to get a Lottie animation to play within SwiftUI. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVehE3Jf7K0) However, I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how to initially present the first frame of the animation, but only have the animation play once a user taps on it in a button format.

My current LottieButton file is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import Lottie

struct LottieButton: UIViewRepresentable {
/// Create a button.
let animationButton = AnimatedButton()
var filename = "LottieLogo2"

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieButton>) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    
    let animation = Animation.named(filename)
    animationButton.animation = animation
    animationButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    
    animationButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(animationButton)
    
    animationButton.clipsToBounds = false
       /// Set animation play ranges for touch states
    animationButton.setPlayRange(fromMarker: "touchDownStart", toMarker: "touchDownEnd", event: .touchUpInside)
       animationButton.setPlayRange(fromMarker: "touchDownEnd", toMarker: "touchUpCancel", event: .touchUpOutside)
       animationButton.setPlayRange(fromMarker: "touchDownEnd", toMarker: "touchUpEnd", event: .touchUpInside)
     
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        animationButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
        animationButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
    ])
    
    return view
    
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieButton>) {
    
    }
}
```

And then I just have a simple view that is displaying the animation:

```
struct InboxView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {}) {
        LottieButton(filename: "inbox-notification")
        .frame(width: 100)
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I handle taps to run a function when using LottieButton? `.onTapGesture` works, but using it the animation doesn't work. Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show `lottie` file only when button pressed, you can set `@State` toggle and show your Lottie when the variable in toggled.

Sample code:

```swift
 @State var toggleValue = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.toggleValue.toggle()
            }) {
                VStack {
                if toggleValue {
                    LottieView(filename: "inbox-notification")
                        .frame(width: 100)
                    }
                    Text("Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I want the initial frame of the animation to show initially, but I only want it to play on tap. So if it was the TwitterHeart, I'd want the heart to show and then when tapped, play and show the fill + explosion animation.

Answer (score 1):

After digging deeper into the Lottie documentation, I saw that there was commented code that showed how to implement an animated button. I edited the code above in LottieButton to set up the button and then I was able to place it into a view and get it to animate on tap. Here is the working code:

```
struct InboxView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack { 
        LottieButton(filename: "inbox-notification")
        .frame(width: 100)
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, solutions go in answers, not edits to the question. You should click the checkmark next to this answer so future readers know it was the solution to your problem.